# Android seekbar clipped thumb

Tags: android, seekbar, clipped

I ran into some weird problem..I implemented a seekbar with custom thumb..and when I ran my app on HTC Desire, it all works fine..but, when I ran it on Samsung Galaxy, the thumb becomes clipped!

Here are the screenshots..

Desire:

[image: Desire seekbar]

Samsung Galaxy:

[image: Galaxy seekbar]

I would be grateful for any thoughts..tnx

myprogress.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/gray"
                android:centerColor="@color/gray"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/gray"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/white"
                    android:centerColor="@color/white"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="@color/white"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#FFA500"
                android:centerColor="@color/yellow"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/yellow"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

style:

```
<style name="mySeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/myprogress</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/thumb</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
```

seekbar xml:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/player_seek_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:max="100" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
        android:layout_width="180dp" 
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        style="@style/mySeekBar" 
        android:background="@drawable/background_transparent_rounded" 
        android:paddingRight="4dp" android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>
```

Comment: Please post relevant XML and source files.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same problem with the default seekbar. Using the `padding` and `thumbOffset` makes it behave differently on different API versions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adjust the `android:paddingLeft`, `android:paddingRight` and `android:thumbOffset` properties of your `SeekBar` to achieve desired results.

Padding right and left should be half of thumb's width.

Comment: If you looked those xmls, you would see that I tried that already..If I set it right for one device, it turns out bad for another

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec, Padding right and left should be half of thumbs width. That should work.

Comment: How do you find out or set the thumb width?

Comment: I set `android:paddingLeft="15dp"` and `android:paddingRight="15dp"`. It worked on all versions of Android on emulator and device that i have tried.

Comment: How to set thumb width? Thanks.

Comment: @faizal, If you have a xml-defined thumb it can be done with <size
        android:height="40dp"
        android:width="40dp" /> inside the shape attribute.

Comment: @Ragunath Jawahar paddingLeft and paddingRight is not doing anything for my seekbar

Answer (score 12):

```
<SeekBar
    ...
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"  
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:thumbOffset="0px" />
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

add following attributes to your parent layout

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: It's OK bro, you're only 7 years late :)

Comment: Great solution. Only needed the clipChildren part in my case. The slight drawback is the thumb will not respond if it is touched on the outer side of the seekBar layout (outer thumb half). This is a minor issue and this approach worked better than the many other options I tried for my situation.